# Refresh my current location iPhone

Tags: iphone, geolocation

Many apps use your "current location" (or what they think is your current location), to make ads relevant to where you are, and other location related app features seem to use this information. Pandora, Spotify, etc. for example play audio ads for businesses near where they think you are.

I went to school in Iowa, but have been living in Chicago Area for 9 months now - yet all of my ads are for businesses in the Iowa City area, among other location based features throughout apps.

Is it possible to update what these apps think you current location is? I have location services and everything activated. It feels like the location is permanently cached as Iowa City.

Comment: I would guess that the ads you are seeing aren't using your phone's *current* location. When I got my first iPhone I went on a road trip to Atlanta, and Yelp (e.g.) is always sending me emails as if I'm from Atlanta. I'm guessing they got my location initially and put it in my user profile somewhere, but the only way to update it is to change it myself. This is just speculation on my part though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset your advertising identifier.

Settings -> Privacy -> Advertising -> Reset Advertising Identifier

This will force iAd to regenerate your advertising profile.